# jQuery Form Validation - success + showErrors

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I'm using the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) and want to run my own code when the plugin detects a valid or invalid input.

I've figured out that the two `.validate()` options I need are `success` and `showErrors` and I can get them both to work on their own:

```
var validator = $('#form').validate({
  rules: {
    name: "required",
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    }
  },
success: function() {
  console.log('success');
}
```

That logs `success` any time a valid input is made. And `showErrors` works correctly also:

```
var validator = $('#form').validate({
  rules: {
    name: "required",
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    }
  },
showErrors: function() {
  console.log('error');
}
```

But when I try to combine the two, `error` is logged every time regardless of whether the input is valid:

```
var validator = $('#form').validate({
  rules: {
    name: "required",
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    }
  },
success: function() {
  console.log('success');
},
showErrors: function() {
  console.log('error');
}
```

The order of the options doesn't have any effect.

Does anyone know why the two options don't work together and how I can run my own functions on valid and invalid inputs?

Comment: I'm having issues with this as well. While the highlight/unhighlight below is helpful, that's not exactly what I want to achieve. showErrors is nice because it gives you the errors as a parameter. Highlight/unhighlight have a separate use case. Would be nice to be able to combine the two.

Answer (score 3):

"showErrors" is not called just when an error is detected, it's called everytime you change the input, regardless the value you typed.

"showErrors" receives two parameters: "errorMap" and "errorList". To verify if there really was an error you have to check one of those values:

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
  if (errorsList.length > 0) {
    console.log('error');
  }
}
```

You can also handle the "success" event inside the showErrors function, since it's called in the current validator context.

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
  if (errorsList.length == 0) {
    this.currentElements.addClass("success");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out... sort of.

I replaced `showErrors` with `highlight`, which allows me to run a callback on either valid or invalid entries.

However, the plugin still displays the default error messages -- probably since I'm not doing anything with `showErrors`. So I had to hack that by setting an empty string for the message on each field:

```
var validator = $('#form').validate({
  rules: {
    name: "required",
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    name: '',
    email: ''
  },
  success: function() {
    console.log('success');
  },
  highlight: function() {
    console.log('highlight');
  }
}
```

Certainly not as clean as I would like, so if anyone has a better way that would be great.

Comment: Thanks - missed that in the docs. When I watch for `unhighlight` in the console, it just triggers every time I click on a field. Is that supposed to be the case?

Comment: By default, blur, keyup, radio/checkbox click, select change, and submit click are the events that trigger validation. Since `unhighlight` removes errors, then yes, scenarios exist where this would be the case.  Construct a jsFiddle example.